# string to a double without calling any built-in utilities

Tags: objective-c

Need to write a function that will convert a string to a double without calling any built-in utilities such as `atof()`, `Double.parseDouble()`, `Double.valueOf()`, `[NSString doubleValue]`, `[NSScanner scanDouble]`, `std::stringstream` or any similar methods.

Comment: What is the format of the string? is it localized? grouping separators? exponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const char *s = "-123.456";
int sign = 1;
int hasdp = 0;
int dplaces = 0;
float f = 0.0;
while(*s) {
    switch (*s) {
    case '-': sign = -1; break;
    case '.': hasdp = 1; break;
    default:
        f *= 10;
        f += *s - '0';
        break;
    }
    s++;
    if (hasdp) dplaces++;
}

f *= sign;
int i;
for (i = 1; i < dplaces; i++) f /= 10;
// we need to start from 1 in order to get
// the correct result, this is a property
// of this algorithm
```

Now `f` will contain the parsed value, provided its format is correct (optional - prefix, optional decimal point followed by 1 or more decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSString *)numberString{
    int i = 0;
    float number = 0.0; 
    while ([numberString length] > i) {
        NSString *myChar = [numberString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        NSLog(@"%@", [numberString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]);
        i++;
        if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            number = number * 10 + 1;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"2"]){
            number = number * 10 + 2;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"3"]){
            number = number * 10 + 3;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"4"]){
            number = number * 10 + 4;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"5"]){
            number = number * 10 + 5;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"6"]){
            number = number * 10 + 6;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"7"]){
            number = number * 10 + 7;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"8"]){
            number = number * 10 + 8;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"9"]){
            number = number * 10 + 9;
        } else if ([myChar isEqualToString:@"0"]){
            number = number * 10 + 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its mentioned not to use any built-in utility like [NSString doubleValue]